# Does this assignment create a copy?

Tags: c++

Will creating this new object, `v`, result in an entirely new object or simply the same object space referenced by `*this`?

`Vector2 v = *this;`

I would not expect it is actually creating a new object, but I'm seeing this code in a sample app that then manipulates this new object even though this code is in a class function that is set as `const`. Thus I would expect that this object,`v`, is in fact entirely a separate memory space than `*this`.

Comment: There is no assignment here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's creating a new object, yes - but by initialization, not assignment.

You can however bypass that by using references, `Vector2& v = *this;`, in which case `v` is an alias for `*this` (or `const Vector& v = *this`, if the method is `const`).

The reasons for this is exactly the one you stated - since the method in which this happens is `const`, there's no way to mutate `*this` - so you need a non-`const` copy of it.

Comment: @andrewx no. Assignment is when you assign to an existing object: `Vector2 v; v = *this;` as opposed to `Vector2 v = *this;`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are inside a `Vector2` method, this operator `=` you are using is called *copy assignment* for a reason. Now, whether it does a deep copy, a shallow copy (copies pointers, but not the objects pointed by them) or whatever is down to the actual implementation of the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `v` is an entirely new object to `*this`.